Invalid Redirect URI with XERO
I am attempting to get my Google Script to use the XERO APIs and am running into problems with the basic authentication.
When I open the authorisation URL, I get the error "Invalid Redirect URI"
I've checked that...

the redirect in my script matches the redirect on the app I created on XERO
the scopes my scripts are requesting are valid
the client_id matches that created in the XERO app.

I've attached my script below (with client/secret removed)
I really would be grateful for some help.
// Script to authenticate with XERO

const CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxxxx';
const CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxx';
const REDIRECT_URI = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxxxxxxxxxx/exec/usercallback'; // Use script's deployment URL

function getOAuthService() {
  return OAuth2.createService('Xero')
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://login.xero.com/identity/connect/authorize')
    .setTokenUrl('https://identity.xero.com/connect/token')
    .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
    .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
    .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
    .setScope('accounting.settings.read offline_access')
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
    .setCache(CacheService.getUserCache());
}

// Step 1: Authorize the app
function authorize() {
  const service = getOAuthService();
  if (!service.hasAccess()) {
    const authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
    Logger.log(authorizationUrl);
    const template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Authorize');
    template.authorizationUrl = authorizationUrl;
    const html = template.evaluate().setWidth(800).setHeight(600);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Authorize App');
  } else {
    Logger.log('Authorization complete. You can now make API requests.');
  }
}

// Step 2: Handle the OAuth callback
function authCallback(request) {
  const service = getOAuthService();
  const isAuthorized = service.handleCallback(request);
  if (isAuthorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success! You can close this window.');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Authorization failed.');
  }
}

// Add doGet function to handle incoming requests
function doGet(e) {
  return authCallback(e);
}

// Step 3: Add an invoice to Xero
function addInvoiceToXero() {
  const service = getOAuthService();

  // Automatically prompt for authorization if needed
  if (!service.hasAccess()) {
    authorize();
    throw new Error('Authorization required. Please authorize the app.');
  }

  const url = 'https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Invoices';
  const invoiceData = {
    "Type": "ACCREC", // Accounts Receivable (sales invoice)
    "Contact": {
      "Name": "John Doe"
    },
    "Date": new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0], // Today's date
    "DueDate": new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 14)).toISOString().split('T')[0], // Due in 14 days
    "LineItems": [
      {
        "Description": "Product/Service Description",
        "Quantity": 1,
        "UnitAmount": 100.00,
        "AccountCode": "200", // Use your chart of accounts code from Xero
      }
    ],
    "Status": "AUTHORISED" // Authorised for sending
  };

  const options = {
    method: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify(invoiceData)
  };

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}


I've made some progress. When deploying the app, it generates a Web App URL which I was using the redirect. I discovered it also generates a Library URL. I switched to using the Library URL and have got past the error.
